# List comprehension

Tags: python, list

I want to fill a list, according to another list with scores. I have found a way but was wondering whether it could be done with list comprehension as well.

I have a list `mood_options` with strings and a list with `weekly_scores` with integers. I use the integers from the `weekly_scores` as an index to pick from the `mood_options` list. Then, these elements picked from `mood_options` are put in a list called `weekly_moods`.

This I how I achieved it with a for loop:

```
    mood_options = ["awful", "bad", "meh", "good", "amazing"]
    weekly_scores = [2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4]

    weekly_moods = []

    for score in weekly_scores:
        weekly_moods.append(mood_options[score-1])
```

As I said, it works, but I have the feeling it can be more concise using list comprehension, however, I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
weekly_moods = [mood_options[score-1] for score in weekly_scores]
```

**Full Code**

```
mood_options = ["awful", "bad", "meh", "good", "amazing"]
weekly_scores = [2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4]

weekly_moods = [mood_options[score - 1] for score in weekly_scores]
print(weekly_moods)
```

**Output**

```
['bad', 'good', 'awful', 'meh', 'good', 'bad', 'good']
```

**References**

- [Python documentation on List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

Comment: Note the `score-1` assumes the moods are 1-indexed. They could also be 0-indexed, in which case just use `score`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be written with a list comprehension:
`[mood_options[i-1] for i in weekly_scores]`

 This takes an i from `weekly_scores` and uses it to take the correct item out `mood_options`